# passing html form post data to different file/webpage javascript variable (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

So I'm trying to pass simple form data from my file `ResName.html`

```
<head>
<form action="file:///E:/programs/portAppJavascript.html" method="post">
    Name: <input id = 'name'>
    <br>
    Number of Reservations: <input type="text" id ='resseats' name="resseat">
    <input type='submit' value="Choose Seats">

</form>

</head>`
```

to my file `portAppJavascript.html`. I'm just trying to pass the number of reservations to a js variable below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var isClicked = false;
var counter = 0;
var numSeatsBought = <?php $_GET['resseat'] ?>; //window.location.search; //change to get from other     html page
var seatArray = new Array();

function clicked(clicked_id){

////////////////
var links = document.head.getElementsByTagName('link');
for(var link in links){
    if(links.hasOwnProperty(link)){
        var l = links[link];
        if(l.rel === 'canonical'){
          alert(l.href);
    }
}
}
```

Why is it not passing the number to the javascript variable? How can I fix this?
`numSeatsBought` is the variable that's not receiving the data correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

1. Your form uses the POST method, but in the next file you check for a GET variable. You should use `$_POST['resseat']` there;
2. You are posting to a file, not a script on a server like `http://localhost/...` so there is no web-server involved and your php will not be processed;
3. The script you are posting to, has the `.html` extension so the php will probably not be processed even if you fix the second problem.